# Create scipt to allow dragging and snapping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that lays out prefabs, on a surface, by creating an array of vectors.  Each array contain 14 vectors, which produce evenly spaced locations, on a plane.

```
public List<Vector3> handEastVectorPoints = new List<Vector3>();
public List<Vector3> handSouthVectorPoints = new List<Vector3>();
public List<Vector3> handNorthVectorPoints = new List<Vector3>();
public List<Vector3> handWestVectorPoints = new List<Vector3>();
```

Then when a prefab is instantiated, my code grabs the correct vector, from the correct array, and add the prefab, like this:

```
public IEnumerator addTileInHand(GameObject tile, Vector3 v, float time, Vector3 rotationVector, int pos)
    {

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationVector);
        GameObject newTile = Instantiate(tile, v, rotation);
        tile.GetComponent<TileController>().canDraw = true;
        tile.GetComponent<TileController>().gameStatus = getCurrentGameState();
        tile.GetComponent<TileController>().currentTurn = sfs.MySelf.Id;

        PlayersHand[pos] = newTile;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    }
```

When this function is called, its passed a vector, which comes from the above array.  The prefab is created, and added to an array of gameObjects.

What I now want to do is allow the player to drag and drop the to various "hot spots", as defined in the first set of arrays (again, their are 14 vectors) and drop them.  If there is already a prefab in that position, I would want it to snap to the new position that just opened up.  If the tile is dropped anywhere else, it should snap back to its original location.  I also just want the object to be dragged either left or right, no need to up and down or up through the Y axis.

Can anyone point me to similar script that might help or provide assistance?

thanks

**Edit: Draggable Script**  Got this working.  You can only drag on the X axis, but for my use case, this works.

```
public class DraggableObject : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool dragging = false;
    private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private float originalY;

    void Start()
    {
        originalY = this.gameObject.transform.position.y;
    }
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, originalY, screenPoint.z));


    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 cursorPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, originalY, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPoint) + offset;
        transform.position = cursorPosition;
        dragging = true;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        dragging = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Might this http://unity.grogansoft.com/word-game-drag-and-snap/ be helpfult?

Comment: hmm.  I am doing this in a 3D project, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a similar thing for my game. This is quite easy. Follow the following steps and let me know if you have any further queries:

- Write a script (let's say ***HolderScript*** ) and add a boolean ***occupied*** to it. Add an [OnTriggerEnter (A Monobehaviour function)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) to the script and update the boolean accordingly:

  *Case 1 - Holder is not occupied* - Make boolean to true and disable Colliders if the prefab is dropped there, else do nothing.

  *Case 2 - Holder is occupied* - if occupied prefab is removed then in [OnTriggerExit function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html) make boolean to false and enable colliders.
- Write a Script (let's say DraggableObject) and set the drag and isDropped boolean accordingly and you can use [Lerp function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) for snapping back.

Attach the holder script to the droppable area and DraggableObject script to the draggable objects.
This should solve your issue.

Comment: Great.  I am still new to Unity.  what should I use for a droppable area? Just a plain with a mesh collider?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am having a difficult time with the drag script.  As this is in Unity3d, I seem to be having some weird issues.  For instance, when I drop the dragged object, sometimes it will hit the surface it was originally resting on and sometimes it will fall right through.  I have added my script above.

Comment: OK, I got a better draggable script.  It only drags on the X axis, but for my use case its fine.

Comment: @jason 1. You can use any bounds for droppable area, for e.g you can make an empty game object and attach a box collider to it. The bounds/size of the box collider can act as Droppable area. Just attach the script to it with required functionalities.

Comment: Thanks.  This has led me down the right track, I think.  Though, it has raised other questions.  I will start a new thread for those.  thanks again!